# I want to clear jtextfile from JFrame1, when I closed JFrame2, What should I do?

Tags: java, swing

When Update Student Information closed, it will refresh data on Student Information System and clear data from search textfield. Please help!

[Please see picture here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67pcZ.png)

Here is what I have tried, but it doesn't work!

```
public class UpdateInfo extends JFrame{
public JPanel pParent;
public JTextField jtfStudentID;
public JTextField jtfStudentName;
public JTextField jtfGender;
public JTextField jtfAddres;

private JButton updateButton;
private JButton cancelButton;
private StudentList stu;

public UpdateInfo() {
    super("Update Student Information ");
    setContentPane(pParent);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 350));
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            stu = new StudentList();
            stu.jtfSearch.setText("");
            dispose();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You can call  `WindowListener` on your frame, on closing action of frame you can do whatever you want. Read more on `WindowListener` [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add an ActionListsner on the cancel button, so that when clicked, JFrame2 is closed and the JTextField is set to " " using the method .setText

Answer (score 0):

JFrame has an dispose_on_close action. when jframe has closed. searchTextfield set  ' "" ' and. if is there a table behind the jframe.

DefaultTableModel.add(// new item);

Please, share codes with us.